# XFCE4 Network Manager

Tags: network-manager, xfce, xfce-panel

My standard Kubuntu 10.04 installation works perfectly but now I'm trying the lighter xfce window manager. I can't find any gui tool to configure networks. Someone on the web talks about the gnome applets container but I don't want to use gnome. 
How to configure network in xfce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XFCE doesn't have its own network manager. Use wicd instead (pygtk-based).

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

Answer (score 5):

Xubuntu 10.04 comes with some GNOME applications such as the Network Manager, just tried on a fresh install:

[image]

Don't know what is used in Xubuntu 10.10, but I doubt it's much different. If you're not happy with Network Manager you can always switch to [WICD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) as karthick87 suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Xfce's own [`Airconfig`](http://spuriousinterrupt.org/projects/airconfig/) has never lifted off and is currently unreleased, abandoned and unmaintained. As suggested in other answers, Xfce users usually use `NetworkManager` or `Wicd`.

Answer (score 1):

Still having this issue on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Xubuntu) and the solution is to enable both Notification Area and Indicator Panel to the XFCE panel. This was pointed out in the following post: [how to display network manager icon on xfce panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517467/how-to-display-network-manager-icon-on-xfce-panel#517688)