# Moved to XFCE and it isn't connecting to ethernet correctly

Tags: networking, network-manager, xfce

I moved from default GNOME to XFCE because I think it's more minimalistic and even more powerfull.
The problem is that for some reason it does not connect to network normally. Everytime when I first log in after boot I need to wait a few seconds to connect to the internet. Today I could connect to network only after 2 reboots.
 I checked out about this issue on google, the only thing I could find was this: [XFCE4 Network Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19024/xfce4-network-manager). Almost all of the users says that xfce network is deprecated, and it's better to use wicd. However, the post was made 10 years ago and wicd does no exist anymore in the repos of ubuntu, most probably because wicd is deprecated now:

```
Package wicd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

My second assumption would be that XFCE network is somehow interfering with automated GNOME network service. However... I can't think of any answer for this.

My computer has only enp4s0. OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64.

Mention: Sometimes it connects, sometimes not, the time can deferr as well from instant after loggin in to probably infinite.

Comment: I don't really follow your question. Ubuntu & Xubuntu are both built on the same Ubuntu base; so there should be no differences with how they access your hardware. Also Xubuntu (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xubuntu-desktop) uses the same tools if you look (`network-manager-gnome`, etc) for 20.04.  I wonder how you converted your GNOME system to XFCE; as I'd expect no ill effects with how I'd do that conversion; but your method may differ as you've given no specifics/details.

Comment: I can't really tell either what the problem is. All I know is that the problem began when I installed xfce4. Logging in ubuntu's GNOME will have the exact problem. The first assumption would be that there are 2 auto network services fighting eachother, one from GNOME, one from XFCE. The way I installed XFCE was by sudo apt install xfce4, choosed lightdm as login manager, then simply logged in XFCE selecting xfce instead of UBUNTU GNOME. I don't really know what network managers each use, tho I can see you sent me what GNOME uses, and now I have a better clarification of what I should search